# error when trying to add gnuplot histogram labels

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot, and I am trying to plot this data (gnuplot receives this input from stdin):

```
Regular 5
Block 3
Symbolic 8
Char 3
Socket 7
```

with this gnuplot code:

```
set style data histograms
set style fill solid
set terminal png
set output "plot.png"

plot '-' using 2:xtic(1), \
    '' using 0:($2 + .1) with labels notitle
```

I get the error `Not enough columns for this style`. What am I doing wrong? If I remove the last line with labels, I am able to plot the histogram. How can I modify it to get data labels on top of each histogram bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three columns of information `x y text` are needed for `with labels`. You gave coordinates but no actual text.  Try

```
$DATA << EOD
Regular 5
Block 3
Symbolic 8
Char 3
Socket 7
EOD

set style data histograms
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:*]
plot $DATA using 2:xtic(1), \
    '' using 0:($2 + .1):2 with labels notitle
```

[image]

Comment: This works by itself since the data is predefined, but I wrote a program which pipes its outputs to the stdin of gnuplot, so the data wouldn't be predefined like with `EOD` above. Everything works if run the code without the last line (with labels), so Im not sure why it breaks when I add that line. I'm getting a `Skipped data file with no valid points`

Comment: The problem with using in-line data via `"-"` is that you can only use it once.  If you want to use it a second time (in this case same data once `with histograms` and a second time `with labels`) you have to repeat the whole input stream. The idea with using a named data block is to have the program sending the data prefix it with `$DATA << EOD`, then send the data, then send the `EOD`.  So it's still piped via stdin but it's wrapped into a datablock definition.

Comment: I am so stupid, I have just figured it out right before you sent this. I am now printing `$DATA << EOD` first, then printing the data, then `EOD`, and then running all the `set` commands, before doing the `plot` command you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plot 'input_file' using 2, '' using 0:2:1 with labels offset 0, char 1
```

Note that I have added the values in a file named `input_file` and have set `set yrange [0:10]` to make the plot nicer to watch

This gives:
[image]

Comment: This works, but the labels are inversed which can be easily fixed. However, my intent was to take input from STDIN (eg a C program would do a printf with appropriate data, and it would be piped into stdin of gnuplot), not get data from a file